# Provisional vaccine for fast spreeding new viruses?

Tags: immunology, virology, epidemiology, vaccination, host-pathogen-interaction

Developing a standard vaccine for coronavirus will take at least a few months - what might be too late:
[image]

However, its sequence is already known, and is nearly identical - suggesting a recent single point of origin for human host, e.g.

> "The researchers also found that the eight complete 2019-nCoV genomes were more than 99.98 percent identical" https://www.genomeweb.com/genetic-research/coronavirus-genome-sequencing-finds-distinct-genetic-differences-2003-sars-virus

So the question is **if/how there could be quickly started production of some provisional vaccine** - not perfect but fast to introduce? Also exploiting the fact that these viruses are now nearly identical.

For example synthesizing its outside proteins and putting them on liposomes - would its introduction to blood have a chance to prepare immune system for the real virus?

Comment: I think the main issue about developing a new vaccine is not that it it's supposed to be perfect - but that it's **safe**. You can just quickly put out medicine without rigorously testing for any side effects

Comment: Fake virus: e.g. liposome exposing some material of the virus, seems easy to synthesize and safe(?) - definitely safer than the real virus, and preparation of the immune system it could provide(?) might be a matter of life and death (?) Sure, in normal situation there are needed time consuming clinical tests, but the question here is about situation when time is literally translated into deaths, and it is approximately known where the virus will strike?

Comment: Perhaps you should address yourself to sites or texts related to clinical virology. People spend their lives working in this area. This site does not exist to solicit the opinions of people whose expertise you know nothing about theories of curing diseases based on no expertise whatever. If you think you are in “A race to save mankind from destruction” you may have been watching too many movies.

Comment: I have added the exponential growth plot to remind how serious this situation is, and generally ask if there is some "provisional vaccine" - not perfect, but which could be introduced before it spreads over the world. The comments suggest the answer is 'no', but could anybody elaborate with support of some materials?

Comment: Some discussion: https://www.scienceforums.net/topic/121181-provisional-vaccine-for-fast-spreading-new-viruses/

Comment: Stack Exchange Biology does not have the remit or expertise to answer questions about coronaviruses relating to the recent 2019-nCoV outbreak. We have compiled [a list of what we regard as reputable external sources of such information](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036). Please consult that.